# What is the difference between heap member and the reference of one?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, reference, heap-memory

I got this copy constructor from a book and added the cout to compare the values:

```
Person::Person(const Person& c) {
    m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
    m_Age = c.m_Age;

    cout << m_pName << " " << &m_pName;
}
```

The cout will output 2 different addresses. The book I'm reading doesn't define what the m_pName is on its own without the &, it only says that &m_pName is the heap member address. What is the address returned without the & operator?

edit: Here is the class and constructor:

```
class Person() {
public:
    Person(const string& name = 0);
    Person(const Person& c);
private:
    string* m_pName;
}

Person::Person(const string& name) {
    m_pName = new string(name);
}
```

Comment: The two addresses are what the pointer points to and the pointer variable itself.

Comment: ***it only says that &m_pName is the heap member address*** That depends on if Person is on the heap.

Comment: m_pName is a pointer to a string. I think you can tell by the line: new string(*(c.m_pName)) where it is dereferenced but I updated the question with a class and constructor to make clearer.

Comment: so &m_pName is the address of the pointer and m_pName is the address of the new string?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: are both stored in the heap? thanks

Comment: ***are both stored in the heap?*** That depends on where `Person` exists. If your `Person` object is on the stack. `&m_pName` is a location on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you've provided it looks like `m_pName` is a pointer to `string` (to an `std::string` perhaps), so `m_pName` without an ampersand is the address of that string, just allocated.